# ANOVA assumptions without raw data?

Tags: anova, assumptions

I have several mean values (with standard deviations and sample sizes) that I would like to compare. However, I do not have the raw data. Is there a way to test the assumptions of ANOVA in this case? And can I use the Kruskal-Wallis test on these data?

Answer (score 1):

There's one assumption of ANOVA that can be assessed from standard deviations *plus the numbers of observations in the groups*, which is the assumption of equal variances. If the standard deviations differ strongly between groups, this can be problematic. There are formal tests for this (e.g., the Levene test). Standard software will compute this from the raw data, so you'd have to do your own calculations in this case. If you don't have numbers of observations, nothing can be done.

Other assumptions cannot be tested with the given information. Whether mean values and standard deviations are appropriate to summarise the data already relies on these assumptions.